# I'm not very good in coding and I'm having a few problems with my Hangman Game

Tags: javascript, html, alerts

I am just beginning to learn how to use javascript and I'm having a few issues with my code. We are asked to make a hangman game and I have developed the necessary code to make the "right" letter and "wrong" letter loops work. However, I need my code to display asterisk symbols not boxes that the letters go in. I also need it to congratulate the user when they have guessed the word correctly. I am assuming the easiest thing to do would be to have it "alert" the user. This part isn't required but I would also like to know how to add the "hangman" images to the code. So say the user guesses a wrong letter, it would then build the hangman from the images.

I know I'm asking a lot but the asterisks part instead of boxes and the alert is what I'm really looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my html code to go with my javascript code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HangmanProgram</title>    
</head>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
<body>
<H1><bold><center> Hangman Program</h1>
<h3> The Hangman Game.
<br>     
Click Start Game button. Type a letter in the "Guess" box and then click "Guess". 
<br> 
Click Reset button to play again.
<br>
<br>

<Form name = "hangmanForm">
<input type="button" value="Start Game" onclick="getword()"><br>
<!-- Hidden field for storing answer -->
<input type="hidden" name="answer" value=""/> 
<input type="button" value="Guess" onclick="formCheck()">
<input name = "ltr" type="text" size = "1"><br>

<br>The Word is:
<input name = "letterone" type="text" size = "1">
<input name = "lettertwo" type="text" size = "1">
<input name = "letterthree" type="text" size = "1">
<input name = "letterfour" type="text" size = "1">
<BR>
<BR>
Wrong Letters<input name = "wrongletters" type="text" size = "24">
<BR>
<BR>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

**below is my javascript code**

```
// Get a random number
function get_random()
{
  document.hangmanform.ltr.focus();
    var ranword= Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    return ranword;
    }

    // Fetch the possible words using random number and array of choices
function getword()
    {
        var userguess=get_random();

    var words =new Array(11);
        words[0]="note";
        words[1]="duck";
        words[2]="cake";
        words[3]="lake";
        words[4]="stop";
        words[5]="know";
        words[6]="dogs";
        words[7]="play";
        words[8]="fair";
        words[9]="sexy";
        words[10]="love";

        var answer = words[userguess];

        // Set hidden field to answer.
        hangmanform.answer.value = answer;

    }

    function formCheck()
    {
    // Read answer and decide if guess is in the string.
        var answer = hangmanform.answer.value;
        var vposition = answer.indexOf(hangmanform.ltr.value);

    // If it is not the word, add to wrong letters box.
        if (vposition == -1) {
            hangmanform.wrongletters.value = hangmanform.ltr.value + " " + hangmanform.wrongletters.value;
        }
        else {

            // Guess in string
            switch (vposition) {
                case 0:
                hangmanform.letterone.value = answer.substring(0,1);
                break;
                case 1:
                hangmanform.lettertwo.value = answer.substring(1,2);
                break;
                case 2:
                hangmanform.letterthree.value = answer.substring(2,3);
                break;
                case 3:
                hangmanform.letterfour.value = answer.substring(3,4);
            }

        }

        // Set form guess box to empty string NOT SPACE
        hangmanform.ltr.value ="";
        hangmanform.ltr.focus();
    }
```

Comment: You have several html tags that open, and aren't matched with closign tags like here: `<H1><bold><center> Hangman Program</h1>` where the `<bold>` is going to continue to apply to what follows the `<h1>`. Similarly at the end of your html you close your `</head>` again after closing the `</body>`, but it should be `<html><head></head></body></body></html>`. Clean html makes working with JavaScript much easier.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/pL7jk/2/ for some slightly cleaner html and a few design notes to consider regarding `<input>` vs `<span>` for elements that the user doesn't need to interact with. Note that center for the `<h1>` is moved to .css

Comment: I have cleaned up my code but I still don't know how to display asterisk symbols instead of the "boxes" that the correct letters go. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. So, `name`, `Name`, and `NAME` are considered different identifiers that can be used at the same time for different values.

In this case, it means that each of the references to `hangmanform` (lowercase) in the script should be `hangmanForm` (camelCase) to match the case used by `<form name="hangmanForm">`.

```
// ...

function formCheck()
{
// Read answer and decide if guess is in the string.
    var answer = hangmanForm.answer.value;
    var vposition = answer.indexOf(hangmanForm.ltr.value);

// ...
```

---

Also, though automatic globals are becoming standard, it's still not necessarily a good practice to depend on them as they can still collide with other uses of global variables.

```
// ...

function formCheck()
{
// Read answer and decide if guess is in the string.
    var form = document.getElementsByName('hangmanForm')[0];
    var answer = form.answer.value;
    var vposition = answer.indexOf(form.ltr.value);

// ...
```

[MDN: `getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

Comment: Okay I am now seeing the game isn't resetting and allowing a new word to by placed when you "click" reset. I am also still not showing the asterisk symbols where the "empty" boxes are for the letters in the word. Any chance you know how I can get that?

Answer (score 0):

A `<span>` can be `<span id="letters">* * * *</span>` and can be addressed with:

```
var letters = document.getElementById('letters'),
    chars = letters.textContent.split(' ');
chars[2] = 'X'; // change the third * to the letter X
letters.textContent = chars.join(' ');
```